# Como ocultar menus en Android

Tags: android-studio, menú

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**como se muentra en la imagen necesito ocultar ciertos menus dependiendo del tipo de cuenta.**

estoy utilizando el Activity de Navigation Drawer, he visto que en el `onCreateOptionsMenu` puedo hacerlo pero no se en realidad como se debe hacer eso, alguien que me ayude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Podes ocultar los items una vez que tenes la referencia al NavigationView. Por ejemplo.

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_registrar_corte).setVisible(false);
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.action_mostrar_corte).setVisible(true);
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En este menú puedes optar por no mostrar un grupo en lugar de todos los elementos del grupo mediante:

```
navigationView.getMenu().setGroupVisible(R.id.grupo1, false);
```

O un elemento del grupo:

```
navigationView.getMenu().findItem(R.id.elemento1).setVisible(false);
```